# Android Glide Library - Argument must not be null

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-glide

I have a recyclerView. When I click on a item in the Recyclerview, I want to add a picture to the imageview in my activity. I try using Glide and it doesn't. I get this error: Argument must not be null. I think the problem is: imageView is not in Recyclerview. That's why I can't access Imageview from my Adapter class. How do I fix this?

**Adapter Class**

NOTE: imageView is not in Recyclerview.

```
     public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
              super(itemView);

              image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
              imageViews =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.cards);
              imageViews.setOnClickListener(this);
          }


 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == imageViews){
                 Glide.with((MainActivity)context).load(R.drawable.picture).fitCenter().into(image);
            }

        }
```

**main activity XML**

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/examplePicture" />
```

**LOGCAT**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:25)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:685)
        at com.example.android.TarotModule.CustomAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:82)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

Instead of

```
 image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I used this

```
image = ((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the if condition. The ```v can never be equal to the image

Comment: Replace ```(MainActivity)context``` by getBaseContext